# Change home page url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

In my framework, the home page is

```
http://localhost:8585/web1/dashboard
```

I want to change that url of the home page to

```
http://localhost:8585/web1/
```

I've tried both `RewriteRule ^dashboard(.*)$ $1` and `RewriteRule ^(index)$ /dashboard [L]` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Let's dive in to the rules you have provided!

`RewriteRule ^dashboard(.*)$ $1` Looking at the `(.*)` The meaning of the dot is that it can be any character (but only one). So `.*` means that it can be a lot of character. This is typically used to capture the entire requested url, without the domain. The `$` at the end means quite literally that the host ends with the requested url (remember; that's without the domain) thus making no sense. How you should use these rules in a 301 redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In this example we redirecting any traffic that is hitting our server, capturing the requested url and redirecting it to example.com with the captured url passed down as a parameter `$1`.

`RewriteRule ^(index)$ /dashboard` I can see where you are going with the second rewrite url. Trying to capture the index group and redirecting it to dashboard. In itself is a valid way to describe it but wrongly implemented. Based on our first explanation the `(index)$` group states the requested url has to be `index` or else this rule won't be met. So.. that means it's never met because the url never will be just `index`.

What you have to do:
If you just want to redirect the dashboard page to web1/ you use a rule as follows:

```
RewriteRule    ^web1/dashboard/?$    web1/   [NC,L]
```

This rule works for rewriting "http://localhost/web1/dashboard" to "http://localhost/web1/". However if you have pages behind the dashboard that need to be redirected as well you can apply this rule:

```
RewriteRule    ^web1/dashboard/(.*)$    web1/$1   [NC,L]
```

Can you spot the difference? ;-)

Some sources:

- [htaccess tester, brilliant tool](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)
- [URL Rewriting Guide - Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)